# Transaction Error while installing memcached.x86_64 & php-pecl-memcache.x86_64

Tags: centos, memcached

On executing

```
 yum install memcached.x86_64 php-pecl-memcache.x86_64
```

I am getting this error:

```
Transaction check error: 
file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 conflicts 
with file from package ea-php-cli-0.2.0-1.1.1.cpanel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution finally worked for me:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/PHP+PECL