# Facing issues with installation of memcache php, centos 6

Tags: php, memcached, centos6, libmemcache

I am following below link to install memcache

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-memcached-php-extension-on-centos-7/

*When I run* 
**yum -y install php-pecl-memcache**

got error

> Transaction Check Error:   file /usr/bin/php from install of
>   php-cli-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   ea-php-cli-1.0.0-7.7.1.cpanel.x86_64

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348809/transaction-error-while-installing-memcached-x86-64-php-pecl-memcache-x86-64